# h-oscillating function

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fa.functional-analysis

I need help understanding the following condition:

$u_h\in L^2(\mathbb{T}^d)$, $\|u_h\|_{L^2(\mathbb{T}^d)}=1$, where $h$ is the semiclassical parameter and $\mathbb{T}^d$ is the flat torus, is called $h$-oscillating if

$\limsup_{h\rightarrow0^+}\|1_{[0,R]}(h^2\Delta) u_h\|_{L^2(\mathbb{T}^d)}\underset{R\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$

Any examples, counterexamples, help are appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: In particular, are eigenfunctions of $h^2\Delta$ $h$-oscillating?